# Pygame displays Black screen ("Pro Python "Best Practices")

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Ive taken this code from book "Pro Python Best Practices", but cannot run the game. It shows me black screen, after running this code:

```
from load_tiles import load_tiles
from generate_maze import create_maze
from event_loop import event_loop
from draw_maze import draw_grid, parse_grid
from moves import move, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN
from pygame import Rect
import pygame


DIRECTIONS = {
    276: LEFT, 275: RIGHT,
    273: UP, 274: DOWN
}


def draw():
    """Displays the maze on the screen"""
    img = draw_grid(maze, tile_img, tiles)
    display.blit(img, Rect((0, 0, 384, 224)), Rect((0, 0, 384, 224)))
    pygame.display.update()


def handle_key(key):
    """Handles key events in the game"""
    direction = DIRECTIONS.get(key)
    if direction:
        move(maze, direction)
    draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize display
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    display = pygame.display.get_surface()
    tile_img, tiles = load_tiles()

    # prepare the maze
    maze = parse_grid(create_maze(12, 7))
    maze[1][1] = '*'
    maze[5][10] = 'x'

    # start the game
    draw()
    event_loop(handle_key)
```

Terminal does not show me any errors. It's just run black screen. Ive tried to find similar problems, but in most cases the problem is in code. According to book it have to work. I would appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a copy of this book, and it has a number of requirements in a textfile on the github directory where i assume you pasted this code from. Ensure you have all the requirements as this is likely the issue